# Searching for category with subcategories in javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, filtering

I'm building a search functionality where I need to search for a specific value to be find by part of its text.
So I've got an example object:

```
const data = [
  {
    org_name: "A PFS COUNTRY TESTS",
    clients: [
      {
        name: "Abu Dhabi",
        type: "Yacht",
        currency: "EUR",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Australia",
        type: "Yacht",
        currency: "AUD",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Bermuda",
        type: "Yacht",
        currency: "EUR",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    org_name: "Music Tours",
    clients: [
      {
        name: "Music Demo",
        type: "Office",
        currency: "GBP",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Summer Tour",
        type: "Office",
        currency: "GBP",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Winter Tour",
        type: "Yacht",
        currency: "USD",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    org_name: "Dariusz Sandbox 1",
    clients: [
      {
        name: "Dariusz Test Client 1",
        type: "Yacht",
        currency: "EUR",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Dariusz Test Client 2",
        type: "House",
        currency: "GBP",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      },
      {
        name: "Dariusz Test Client 3",
        type: "Aircraft",
        currency: "USD",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    org_name: "Dariusz Sandbox 2",
    clients: [
      {
        name: "Dariusz Test Client 1",
        type: "Yacht",
        currency: "EUR",
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0
        }
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

So if I'm looking for a "Dar" I should receive array with only org_name objects that have clients that include the "Dar" in their name value.

My solution is so far:

```
const newData = data.map((el) => {
  const filtered = el.clients.filter((client) => {
    if (client.name.includes("Dar")) {
      return client;
    }
  });
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    return { org_name: el.org_name, clients: filtered };
  }
  
});

console.log("newData is", newData);
```

But what I've got is `[undefined, undefined, Object, Object]`
instead of `[Object, Object]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `map` function is always returning - but if it doesn't return anything, it will return undefined. You can use `filter`, as in @STW's answer, or you can use `reduce` to only get the ones you want.

```js
const data = [
  {
    org_name: 'A PFS COUNTRY TESTS',
    clients: [
      {
        name: 'Abu Dhabi',
        type: 'Yacht',
        currency: 'EUR',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Australia',
        type: 'Yacht',
        currency: 'AUD',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Bermuda',
        type: 'Yacht',
        currency: 'EUR',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    org_name: 'Music Tours',
    clients: [
      {
        name: 'Music Demo',
        type: 'Office',
        currency: 'GBP',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Summer Tour',
        type: 'Office',
        currency: 'GBP',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Winter Tour',
        type: 'Yacht',
        currency: 'USD',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    org_name: 'Dariusz Sandbox 1',
    clients: [
      {
        name: 'Dariusz Test Client 1',
        type: 'Yacht',
        currency: 'EUR',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Dariusz Test Client 2',
        type: 'House',
        currency: 'GBP',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'Dariusz Test Client 3',
        type: 'Aircraft',
        currency: 'USD',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    org_name: 'Dariusz Sandbox 2',
    clients: [
      {
        name: 'Dariusz Test Client 1',
        type: 'Yacht',
        currency: 'EUR',
        notifications: {
          for_action: 0,
          for_attention: 0,
        },
        unpaid_invoices: {
          total: 0,
          ok_to_pay: 0,
          reviewed: 0,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

const newData = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const filtered = el.clients.filter((client) => {
    if (client.name.includes('Dar')) {
      return client;
    }
  });

  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    acc.push({ org_name: el.org_name, clients: filtered });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot @yainspan

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your `map()` call.  It will return an Object (your org) if it has at least one client that passes the `filter()`, but implicity returns `undefined` if `filtered.length` is not greater than zero.

In JS every function has a return -- either declared with `return`, or implicit.  The default implicit value is `undefined` which is where those array entries are coming from.  You could switch `map()` to `filter()` and it should work (since it will omit the falsy `undefined` values from the array).

```js
const newData = data.filter((el) => { # NOTE: the change to .filter()
  const filtered = el.clients.filter((client) => {
    if (client.name.includes("Dar")) {
      return client;
    }
  });
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    return { org_name: el.org_name, clients: filtered };
  }
  
});

console.log("newData is", newData);
```

Comment: It doesn't give the result I'm expecting. It returns org_names with all its clients where I need org_names with matching clients only. 
But thank you anyway, I was able figure it out ofter your help.